# How to remove multiple key at a single command from session in laravel

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

Let's say I have a session array like

```
array(
     'boking' = array(
                    'index1' => 'value1'
                    'index2' => 'value2'
               ),
     'return' = array(
                    'index1' => 'value1'
                    'index2' => 'value2'
               ),
     'search' = array(
                    'index1' => 'value1'
                    'index2' => 'value2'
               )
)
```

Now I want to remove `boking` and `search`

To do this task I have try

```
Session::forget('boking');
Session::forget('search');
```

It works fine.

But I want to remove this multiple key in one command.
Is there any possibilities to do that in one command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php) `Session::forget` is defined as

```
/**
 * Remove an item from the session.
 *
 * @param string $key
 * @return void
 */
 public function forget($key)
 {
     array_forget($this->attributes, $key);
 }
```

The [`array_forget`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L169) function is defined as

```
/**
 * Remove one or many array items from a given array using "dot" notation.
 *
 * @param array $array
 * @param array|string $keys
 * @return void
 */
 function array_forget(&$array, $keys)
 {
     return Arr::forget($array, $keys);
 }
```

Since `Session::forget` does not enforce any type on `$key` and passes whatever you pass to it to `array_forget`, which accepts `array|string $keys`, you should be able to do

```
Session::forget(['boking', 'search']);
```

However, because `Session::forget` does not list `array` as a possible value for `$key` and explicitly names the param in the singular form, you should not rely on that behavior. It might change. Then again, it also might just be a documentation bug. Consider opening a ticket with the Laravel guys.

For the sake of completeness and reference here is the code to [`Arr::forget`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php#L171):

```
/**
 * Remove one or many array items from a given array using "dot" notation.
 *
 * @param  array  $array
 * @param  array|string  $keys
 * @return void
 */
public static function forget(&$array, $keys)
{
    $original =& $array;

    foreach ((array) $keys as $key)
    {
        $parts = explode('.', $key);

        while (count($parts) > 1)
        {
            $part = array_shift($parts);

            if (isset($array[$part]) && is_array($array[$part]))
            {
                $array =& $array[$part];
            }
        }

        unset($array[array_shift($parts)]);

        // clean up after each pass
        $array =& $original;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try following this code:**

```
Session::forget(['test1', 'test2']);
```